# Remove schema name from DBeaver's query

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

I am new to DBeaver and I am using it for the postgres client. I was using Navicat before and in navicat the query simply used to run without schema name as  `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME` . However, I am having issues with the Navicat and I recently switched on DBeaver(22.0.4 mac). With DBeaver, I cannot execute query without schema name before tablename which is like `SELECT * FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME`. Is there any option to just define my SCHEMA as a default schema in DBEAVER so that I can run query just by the tablename ?

Comment: Best way to deal with is to use [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) in Postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your connection settings in dbeaver unter Initialization you can set a default schema:

[image: dbeaver settings]